# Want to run a .py program as in terminal at start up

Tags: gnome-terminal, startup, python3

I want to run a .py program as my computer starts up .
I went to startup application and selected that .py program to run.
But that did not work , terminal did not open. 
What to do?

Comment: Do you want it to run in the background or do you need the terminal window?

Comment: What is the script and what should it do? Is the script executable? Do you call the terminal *from* the script?

Answer (score 1):

Use `gnome-terminal`:

```
gnome-terminal -e "python /path/to/file.py"
```